# Problems with the matplotlib plots in LaTeX

Tags: xetex

I'm having some troubles with importing pdf figures into XeLaTeX from matplotlib. The text floats over a figure. What should I do with that problem?
This is a simple figure latex code i used:

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\includegraphics[width=15.92cm]{figure_1.eps}
\end{tabular}
\caption{.....)\label{fig1}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

And thats a text:
`\section{Some text}\label{sec4}`

Comment: This might not necessarily be the problem, but don't use a `center` environment inside of `figure`, instead use `\centering`. Also, there is no need to put `tabular` around `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Your text says PDF, your code says EPS. Have you tried both?

Comment: Yes, I tried both of them.